# Select data from one table, arrange by a sum of data from another

Tags: php, select, mysqli, sum

A client is looking for a points system to be implemented on her website, I'm struggling to display the users based upon the amount of points collected, I hope somebody may be able to help me out here and point me in the right direction to getting this code to work properly.

I am selecting all data from `ap_users` and in the code I am also trying to select all data from `ap_points` although I do not require all the data from either tables, to be specific I only require:

```
ap_users:
     user_id
     first_name
     last_name
     display_img
     hub_access

ap_points:
     user_id
     points_added
```

I thought that selecting ALL data may be the easiest route, will let you decide.

I am trying to select and display all users where `hub_access = '1'` and order by the total `points_added` by highest first. Points are added separately by rows and need to be added up (which is why I have the `sum` function).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ap_users`, `ap_points` WHERE `hub_access` = '1' ORDER BY sum(points_added) DESC";
```

I also tried configuring it to be specific tables like:

`ap_users.hub_access` and `ORDER BY sum(ap_points.points_added)` but these did not work either.

This current code is either showing no results or a single result with no errors displaying? I'm not sure whether I may need to use some kind of `Group By` function to connect the user_ids from both tables ?

Comment: Do you have records in those tables? select a.user_id,a.first_name,a.last_name,a.display_img,sum(b.points_added)  total_points from ap_users a,ap_points b
    where a.hub_access=1
    group by a.user_id
    order by sum(b.points_added)

Comment: Yeah defiantly have records in the tables, if I edit the SQL to be simple, it does display records, it's only when I try to order them or so. And where you have `sum(b.points_added) total_points` should that be like that or should it be `sum(b.points_added) as total_points`?

Comment: Try it with 'as'. I am not familiar with mysql syntax.

Comment: It is working, and displaying results although it is counting up all points in the system rather than grouping them by `user_id` so all users have the same amount of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUM is an aggregating function. You should be grouping by user_id if you want the sum for each user_id.

Something like

```
SELECT *, sum(points_added) as sum_points FROM app_users 
JOIN app_points ON app_users.user_id = app_points.user_id
WHERE `hub_access` = '1' 
GROUP BY app_users.user_id
ORDER BY sum_points;
```

I have not tested that query, but that should give you an idea of the solution.

Comment: Worked first time without an issue what so ever. You sir, are a life saver! Thanks very much for the help and for providing a bit more knowledge on the topic.